# MongoDB uuidRepresentation Java issue

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to currently connect to my mongodb database in java with uuidRepresentation enabled. When trying to do this i receive this error

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256, userName='admin', source='authDb', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 17 (ProtocolError): 'Attempt to switch database target during SASL authentication.' on server 185.209.223.136:2002. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Attempt to switch database target during SASL authentication.", "code": 17, "codeName": "ProtocolError"}
```

Here is how I am connecting to my mongo database

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://admin:<nopasswordforyou>@185.209.223.136:2002/authDb?uuidRepresentation=javaLegacy");

        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("bans");
```